# How to preload images for a game in the simplest way possible? (pure js, no library)

Tags: javascript

I want to have `game.js` which will only start execution when all the necessary images have been preloaded. The best way I can think of is something like:

```js
var numberOfImagesToPreload = 2;
var imgsLoadedSoFar = 0;

var sources = ['player.png', 'terrain.png'];

for(let i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
    var anImage = new Image();
    anImage.src = sources[i];
    anImage.onload = function() {
        imgsLoadedSoFar++;
    }
};

console.log(imgsLoadedSoFar);

if(imgsLoadedSoFar === numberOfImagesToPreload) {
    console.log("Done, now start executing game.js");
};
```

Clearly this doesn't work because of async problems and I want to have `preloader.js` that will load the images first and then I want to launch `game.js` in which each image(game object) will have update and draw methods. If you think this shouldn't be done that way please suggest how. Thanks a lot.

---

EDIT

I am making some progress on this. Once the `preloader.js` loads all the resources I call a function in `game.js` `function(image)` but still not what I am looking for, which is basically once game.js starts loaded ALL the images should be loaded already.

Comment: You can't prevent the game.js script from running right when it's loaded, that's done by the browser. You'd have to load it dynamically instead of using a `<script>` tag. But why don't you want a function that can be triggered to run the game code when ready? That seems like the most reasonable approach.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm just thought there is a cleaner way but with callback it works. I wanted to avoid things like function game(assets) { then inside function init(){} then ...} but I guess there isn't a cleaner way, thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `if` inside your loop?

```
for(let i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
    var anImage = new Image();
    anImage.src = sources[i];
    anImage.onload = function() {
        imgsLoadedSoFar++;
        if(imgsLoadedSoFar === numberOfImagesToPreload) {
          console.log("Done, now start executing game.js");
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: That does answer part of the question. Now I am declaring a variable ```imageArray``` and pushing ```anImage``` to it in the onload part. However, when I see the values of ```imageArray``` in my ```game.js``` they are undefined. I have ```preload.js``` with the code to load the images and then ```game.js``` which should execute when the images are loaded but they are undefined. (and yes, in the body of html first I say ```<script src="preloader.js"></script> and right after that <script src="game.js></script>```.

Comment: Your function in `game.js` is probably running before the images have had a chance to load. Putting the `<script>` tags one after the other doesn't enforce sequential order of execution for the scripts. Things would get simpler if you weren't using different js files. But if you want to stick with that approach maybe define a function in `game.js` to receive the array of loaded images, and call that inside your `if` check in your image load loop.

Answer (score 1):

Add a global boolean variable to switch to true only after preloading, wrap the functions on game.js in an if statement, once the boolean becomes true make call the function in game.js